# SvelteKit import type { PageLoad } from "../\"; ERROR

Tags: visual-studio, types, module, svelte, sveltekit

I have this error when importing a module on +page.ts like "PageLoad". Isn't recognizing the modules bc I did changes between JS and TS.
I tried removing node_modules and package-lock.json and then doing a npm install. But doesnt work.
I tried restarting svelte language and typescript but nothing works.

I removed typescript.config and then did a npx tsc --init and I did a npx svelte-kit sync and npm cache clean --force.
But it still doesn't working.
I did it all. Please help me :(. I'm just trying to learn Svelte but i can't use their types.

Greats, Tomás

I want to Vs recognize the module ./$types from SvelteKit